# Save a completion handler as an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I was wondering if there was a way to "save" a completion handeler.

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{

}

- (void)actionHere {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

I want to send the result in a different function as shown above.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### tl;dr

declare a copy property (weird syntax, I know... http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/)

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^completionHandler)(UIBackgroundFetchResult fetchResult);
```

and use it like follows

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    self.completionHandler = completionHandler;
}

- (void)actionHere {
    if (self.completionHandler)
        self.completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

---

#### Discussion

Blocks are full-fledged objects in Objective-C, **BUT** they come with a big difference: by default they are allocated on the stack.

If you want to save a reference to a block you have to copy it on the heap, since retaining a a block on the stack won't prevent it to be lost whenever the stack frame is teared down.

In order to copy a block on the heap you have to call the `Block_Copy()` function. You can optionally call the `copy` method (which will invoke the previous function for you).

Declaring a property with the `copy` attribute will make the compiler to automatically insert a `copy` call whenever you assign the object through the property setter.

Comment: can we save a weak refrence of it

Comment: Just being pedantic.. it should nil out the reference once you're done using it, you never know actionHere might get called a second time.. so self.completionHandler = nil;

Answer (score 2):

Blocks are objects (yes, real ObjC objects!), the only important thing is you have to copy them (not retain) whenever you want to store them for later use.

So you need to do either:

```
_myCompletionHandler = [completionHandler copy];
```

or:

```
_myCompletionHandler = Block_copy(completionHandler);
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the stupid question but so what would I put in an @interface?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to declare a property for your block. Here's the syntax:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);
```

Then you can just say `self.blockName = completionHandler`.

And in `actionHere` just call it like this:

```
self.blockName();
```